# Почему не работает print_r?

Tags: php

По идее этот скрипт должен выводить ссылку. Но он этого не делает и print_r ничего не выводит!

```
<?php
$lol=file_get_contents("http://www.heroeswm.ru/clan_info.php?id=41");
preg_match_all("/Казначей:<\/b> <a class=pi href='([^']+)'>kekus<\/a>/", $lol, $kkaz);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($name);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<strong>Казначей</strong>";
echo "<a href=\"http://www.heroeswm.ru/";
echo $kazn[1][0];
echo "\"target=\"_blank\"> ";
echo $kazn[2][0];
echo "</a>";
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: 2ling: поставь, пожалуйста, разделители строк. Спасибо.

Comment: @knes, так?

Comment: Йес. Так оно как-то лучше, читабельнее

Answer (score 3):

Переменная $name не задана.

Comment: Точно $name не существует!

Comment: Ну... так что ожидается от print_r?